# Computation of a limit involving a series (related to Poisson distribution)

Tags: analysis, statistics

Consider $\lambda >0.$ I am reading a paper and the author states that

$$ \displaystyle\lim_{v \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n !)^v}  = 1 + \lambda$$

I tried to compute such limit but I am getting anywhere. Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n !)^v}=1+\lambda+\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n !)^v}$$and $$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n !)^v}{\le \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{n !}\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n !)^{v-1}}\\\le e^{\lambda}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{(n-1)(v-1)}}\\=e^\lambda{{1\over 2^{v-1}}\over 1-{1\over 2^{v-1}}}\\={e^\lambda\over 2^{v-1}-1}\\\to 0}$$hence the result.

Answer (score 3):

The RHS is obviously the first two terms of the sum. For the remaining terms, replace $n!$ by $2^n$. Then, whatever $\lambda$, for a sufficiently large $v$, you have a convergent geometric series (that tends to zero as $v \to \infty$).